# Php preg_replace with array in elements

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace, emoji

I am trying to do the emoji system and if the element in the array passes through the page, turn the value on the opposite side. Example:

```
 $emoticons = array(
      ':)'    =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="smile" class="img-responsive" />',
      ':-)'   =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="smile" class="icon_smile" />',
      ':D'    =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="smile" class="icon_laugh" />',
      ':d'    =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="laugh" class="icon_laugh" />',
      ';)'    =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="wink" class="icon_wink" />',
      ':P'    =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="tounge" class="icon_tounge" />',
      ':-P'   =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="tounge" class="icon_tounge" />',
      ':-p'   =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="tounge" class="icon_tounge" />',
      ':p'    =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="tounge" class="icon_tounge" />',
      ':('    =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="sad face" class="icon_sad" />',
      ':o'    =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="shock" class="icon_shock" />',
      ':O'    =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="shock" class="icon_shock" />',
      ':0'    =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="shock" class="icon_shack" />',
      ':|'    =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="straight face" class="icon_straight" />',
      ':-|'   =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="straight face" class="icon_straight" />',
      ':/'    =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="straight face" class="icon_straight" />',
      ':-/'   =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="straight face" class="icon_straight" />'
 );
 foreach($emoticons as $icon => $image) {
      $icon = preg_quote($icon);
      $text = preg_replace("~\b$icon\b~",$image,$text);
 }
```

Comment: You cannot use `\b` here, use `"~(?<!\w)$icon(?!\w)~"`. Or `"~(?<!\S)$icon(?!\S)~"`, depending on what context you want to match the emoticons in.

Comment: you'll be **in charge**? lol. anyway, you could try `strtr` route too

Comment: Thank you, but it did not change. If you wrote: <img src = "assets / smiles / smilesblank.png" alt = "smile" class = "img-responsive" />

Comment: If you do not precise what issue you get, we cannot help you more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**preg_replace_callback_array**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback-array.php)

It uses array of patterns->replacement functions almost identical to yours.

I've made a little example for you:

```
<?php

// initial array
$emoticons = [
    ':)'    =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="smile" class="img-responsive" />',
    ':-)'   =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="smile" class="icon_smile" />',
    ':D'    =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="smile" class="icon_laugh" />',
    ':d'    =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="laugh" class="icon_laugh" />',
    ';)'    =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="wink" class="icon_wink" />',
    ':P'    =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="tounge" class="icon_tounge" />',
    ':-P'   =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="tounge" class="icon_tounge" />',
    ':-p'   =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="tounge" class="icon_tounge" />',
    ':p'    =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="tounge" class="icon_tounge" />',
    ':('    =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="sad face" class="icon_sad" />',
    ':o'    =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="shock" class="icon_shock" />',
    ':O'    =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="shock" class="icon_shock" />',
    ':0'    =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="shock" class="icon_shack" />',
    ':|'    =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="straight face" class="icon_straight" />',
    ':-|'   =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="straight face" class="icon_straight" />',
    ':/'    =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="straight face" class="icon_straight" />',
    ':-/'   =>  '<img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="straight face" class="icon_straight" />'
];

// prepare callbacks
$callbacks = [];
foreach ($emoticons as $smileCode => $replacement) {
    // regular expression, nothing smart, just plain replacement
    $regex = '~' . preg_quote($smileCode, '~') . '~';
    $callbacks[ $regex ] = function () use ($replacement) {
        return $replacement;
    };
}

$text = "Hello :), this is cool :P smile and :-| another one";

echo "<pre>\n";
echo preg_replace_callback_array($callbacks, $text);
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment, the page has returned a null value (I think I found it) but will you tell me exactly how it is used?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, you do not need to check for a word boundary when matching emoticons as they are usually glued to some other text. Thus, `\b` is rather redundant and can be removed. If you really want to only target specific contexts, you may consider replacing the first `\b` with `(?<!\w)` (if the emoticon cannot be preceded with a word char) and the second one with `(?!\w)` (no word char after), or use whitespace boundaries, `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)` respectively.

You may sort the keys of the array by length in the descending order (in case there are overlapping emoticons, like `:-||` and `:-|`), build an alternation based regex pattern while `preg_quote`ing the keys, and use a `preg_replace_callback` to replace each key with its corresponding value:

```
array_multisort(array_map('strlen', array_keys($emoticons)), SORT_DESC, $emoticons);        //   IN DESCENDING ORDER
$pattern = '~' . implode("|", array_map(function($x) {return preg_quote($x, '~');}, array_keys($emoticons))) . '~';
echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($m) use ($emoticons) {
       return $emoticons[$m[0]];
    }, "Some :| emoticon :O");
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/OFR867), for the `"Some :| emoticon :O"` string the result is

```
Some <img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="straight face" class="icon_straight" /> emoticon <img src="assets/smiles/smilesblank.png" alt="shock" class="icon_shock" />
```

Comment: The problem is true, but there is something like that you need to change when you find it on the page

Comment: @OsmanCakmak Note there is a caveat right now: if you do not want to match `:D` in `:Dot`, you will have to add `(?!\w)` at the end of the pattern. Or `(?!\S)`. Just as I mentioned in my comment under the original post. With `\b`, you require a word char after a non-word char and vice versa. Please define the right contexts.

Comment: @OsmanCakmak what does *there is something like that you need to change when you find it on the page* mean? Replace `"Some :| emoticon :O"` with the `$text`.